# Cant connect to MySQL when using Debug mode

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, .net, monodevelop

I have written in program in C# which connects to a MySQL database.

```
public bool Connect()
{
    bool OK = true;
    try
    {
        dbcon = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    dbcon.Open();
    }
    catch 
    {
        OK = false;
    }
    return OK;
}
```

For the connection string I am using

```
public string Server   = "localhost";
public string Database = "samplemonitor";
public string UserID   = "root";
public string Password = "password";
public bool Pooling    = false;


public string ConnectionString
{
    get 
    {
        string isPooling;
        if (Pooling)
        {
             isPooling = "true";
        }
        else
        {
            isPooling = "false";
        }

        return string.Format
        (
            "Server={0};Database={1};User ID={2};Password={3};Pooling={4}",
        Server,
        Database,
        UserID,
        Password,
        isPooling
        );
    }
}
```

When I run this in debug mode in mono, the program hangs on the **dbcon.Open();** command

However, when I run this program from outside the debugger, everything works fine.

**EDIT**

Trying Vinicius' Suggestion, to use "Data Source"

I end up with an error message

> e=11001, NativeErrorCode=11001. --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No such host is known
>
> at System.Net.Dns.GetAddrInfo(String name)
>
> at System.Net.Dns.InternalGetHostByName(String hostName, Boolean
>   includeIPv6)
>
> at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(String hostNameOrAddress)
>
> at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetDnsHostEntry(String hostname)
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetDnsHostEntry(String hostname)
>
> at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetHostEntry(String hostname)
>
> at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetStreamFromHost(String
>   pipeName, String hostName, UInt32 timeout)
>
> at MySql.Data.Common.StreamCreator.GetStream(UInt32 timeout)
>
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
>
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
>
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
>
> at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySqlConnectionStringBuilder
>   settings)
>
> at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
>
> at SampleMonitor.LocalDatabaseConnection.Connect() in
>   c:\Dev\Repositories\HD-CMC\trunk\C#\SampleMonitor\SampleMonitor\Control\LocalDatabaseConnection.cs:line
>   394
>
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException (0x80004005): Unable to connect
>   to any of the specified MySQL hosts. ---> System.Exception: Call to
>   GetHostEntry failed after 00:00:00 while querying for hostname
>   'samplemonitor': SocketErrorCode=HostNotFound, ErrorCode

Its interesting that it did not hang on the open command this time

**EDIT**

This is very strange, it just decided to start working. I haven't changed any of the code. Could this be some kind of temperamental bug in Mono??

Comment: The connection string end up being "Server=LOCALHOST;Database=samplemonitor;User ID=root;Password=password;Pooling=false"

I wonder if I there is something wrong with the way I am including the MySQL dll ...

Comment: I usually use "Data Source" instead of DataBase, just give it a try

Comment: Microsoft as well http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7469at0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: This seems to be for a SQL Server connection, not MySQL

Comment: http://www.connectionstrings.com/dotconnect-for-mysql/

Comment: Last suggestion then, maybe it is a typo, but you are missing a ";" at the end of Pooling

Comment: I'm still missing it now. Sometimes I think there is a ghost in my PC. Thanks for your help.