# MySQL connection fails in debug mode

Tags: mysql, debugging, sharpdevelop

I have a strange issue with MySQL connectivity. My environment is

> OS - Microsoft Windows Home Basic
>   IDE - SharpDevelop 4.3.3.9663
>
> MySQL Server - 5.5
>   MySQL Connector - 6.8.3

I created a sample program that connects to the MySQL server in my machine.

```
using System;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace TestBed
{
    class Program
    {
        private static MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn;
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

            connect();

            Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }

        public static void connect()
        {

            string myConnectionString;

            //myConnectionString = "Server=localhost; Port=3306; Database=test; Uid=root; Pwd=Welcome01;"; //works fine in rel mode
            myConnectionString = "Server=127.0.0.1; Port=3306; Database=test; Uid=root; Pwd=Welcome01;"; 

            try
            {
                conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
                conn.Open();
                Console.WriteLine("opened");
            }
            catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was getting the below error in the beginning.

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
   at System.Void MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open()
   at System.Void MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open()
   at static Driver MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create(MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings)
   at Driver MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection()
   at Driver MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection()
   at Driver MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver()
   at Driver MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection()
   at System.Void MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open()
   at static System.Void TestBed.Program.method() in ...\TestBed\Program.cs:line 36
   at static System.Void TestBed.Program.Main(System.String[] args) in ...\Program.cs:line 19
```

I got a hint from this link ([Cant connect to MySQL when using Debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20896747/cant-connect-to-mysql-when-using-debug-mode)) and tried with Release mode. Surprisingly it was able to open the connection!

I analyzed it a bit more and found the below things.

1. It throws the error only if I use Debug->Step over (using F10 keys to debug step by step)!
2. If I just start the app in Debug mode, it connects.
3. I am able to step break points above and below the "connect()" method
4. I can also use step over (with F10 key) to debug other parts of the application, but if I use step over into this method, it takes a long time and throws the same error.

I am not sure whether I am doing anything wrong, or it is a bug with MySQL or SharpDevelop. Has anyone faced this kind of issue? If possible, someone please throw some light on this?

Thanks,
Ganesh Periasamy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright. This has been reported as a bug in SharpDevelop Debugger (http://community.sharpdevelop.net/forums/t/16473.aspx) but no responses from SharpDevelop team for about an year! I will follow up this with them and try to update this thread, in case I get any.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
"Persist Security Info=False;server=127.0.0.1;database=xx;uid=yy;password=zz"
```

Comment: You should follow some Standard format : http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql-connector-net-mysqlconnection/

Comment: I tried "Persist..." but no luck. One update - I uninstalled MySql 5.5 and installed Wamp and am using the mysql server to connect. Now I get

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Length cannot be less than zero.
   at String System.String.InternalSubStringWithChecks(System.Int32 startIndex, System.Int32 length, System.Boolean fAlwaysCopy)
....

pathetic :(

Comment: again if I start the program as "Run without Degbugger (ctrl+f5)" in sharpdevelop, it works fine!